# Programmatically adding bound Gridview to tabPanels

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, tabpanel

I want to add `GridView` programmatically in a `TabPanel`. In fact the tab panels themselves are created programmatically so I want to create a `GridView` for each `TabPanel`.

Here is the code to create the tab panels:

```
while (j < l.Count)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel panel = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();               
    panel.HeaderText = testrub.RubricName.ToString();       
    GridView grid = new GridView();
    grid.DataSource = element.GetElementByRubric(testrub.ID);
    panel.Controls.Add(grid);
    TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(panel);                
    j++;
}
```

As you can see the gridview that I want to create is databound. I would seriously appreciate some help. :)

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: the Tabcontainer shows up with the tabPanels added but the gridview does not show up

Answer (score 0):

Add this one line to your code

```
GridView grid = new GridView();
grid.DataSource = element.GetElementByRubric(testrub.ID);
grid.DataBind();  //  <------ this new line
```

Comment: In fact can I add a new line in the GridView?

Comment: what do you mean "add a new line"?

Comment: Can I insert at the footer of the GridView to add a line in the data table?

Comment: I am not sure but I think you show be able to do `grid.FooterRow.Controls.Add(new TextBox())` or something like that